# How to use .restrack-File to locate memory leaks with ProcDumps for Linux

Tags: memory-leaks, procdumpforlinux

While trying to determine the cause of a memory leak in a .Net 6.0 application running on Linux, in self-contained mode, I found that ProcDump was recently released for Linux.

I set up the creation of dumps with memory leak tracing using the command `procdump -s 600 -n 3 -restrack`.
From this, ProcDump created three dumps and three `.restrack` files.
I can load the dumps in VS2022 or WinDbg and can inspect the content, but am currently clueless as to what to do with the `.restrack` files.

The content of the file looks like this:

```
+++ Leaked Allocation [allocation size: 0x40b8 count:0x21 total size:0x857b8]
    [0x7f24844af3c0] malloc+0x0

+++ Leaked Allocation [allocation size: 0x5558 count:0x18 total size:0x80040]
    [0x7f24844af3c0] malloc+0x0

+++ Leaked Allocation [allocation size: 0x4148 count:0x1f total size:0x7e7b8]
    [0x7f24844af3c0] malloc+0x0
    [0x7f2473cd3260]

+++ Leaked Allocation [allocation size: 0x10000 count:0x5 total size:0x50000]
    [0x7f24844af3c0] malloc+0x0

+++ Leaked Allocation [allocation size: 0x1db8 count:0x25 total size:0x44b98]
    [0x7f24844af3c0] malloc+0x0
    [0x737300632e62696c]

+++ Leaked Allocation [allocation size: 0x200 count:0x1a5 total size:0x34a00]
    [0x7f24844af3c0] malloc+0x0

+++ Leaked Allocation [allocation size: 0x100 count:0x2a3 total size:0x2a300]
    [0x7f24844af3c0] malloc+0x0

+++ Leaked Allocation [allocation size: 0x5580 count:0x5 total size:0x1ab80]
    [0x7f24844af3c0] malloc+0x0

+++ Leaked Allocation [allocation size: 0x8030 count:0x3 total size:0x18090]
    [0x7f24844af3c0] malloc+0x0

+++ Leaked Allocation [allocation size: 0x4000 count:0x1 total size:0x4000]
    [0x7f24844af3c0] malloc+0x0
    [0x7f2483d7ff2a] ThreadLocalModule::AllocateDynamicClass(MethodTable*)+0x6a
    [0x7f2483d802b5] ThreadLocalModule::PopulateClass(MethodTable*)+0x75
    [0x7f2483e23667] JIT_GetGCThreadStaticBase_Helper(MethodTable*)+0xf7
    [0x7f2410330dce]
    [0x7f240fdf8bde]
    [0x7f240f4bf8d9]
    [0x7f241033127a]
    [0x7f240fdf9c9e]
    [0x7f240f4bf8d9]
    [0x7f240f4a79f1]
    [0x7f241031de84]
    [0x7f2483f83597] CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x7c
    [0x7f2483db908e] DispatchCallSimple(unsigned long*, unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned int)+0xfe
    [0x7f2483dd1c12] ThreadNative::KickOffThread_Worker(void*)+0x92
    [0x7f2483d7db4a] ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter(ManagedThreadCallState*)+0x14a
    [0x7f2483d7e14d] ManagedThreadBase::KickOff(void (*)(void*), void*)+0x2d
    [0x7f2483dd1ce7] ThreadNative::KickOffThread(void*)+0xb7
    [0x7f2484117cee] CorUnix::CPalThread::ThreadEntry(void*)+0x24e
    [0x7f248449f832] start_thread+0x2d2

+++ Leaked Allocation [allocation size: 0x3 count:0x1 total size:0x3]
    [0x7f24844af3c0] malloc+0x0
    [0x7f218db2c490]

+++ Leaked Allocation [allocation size: 0x3 count:0x1 total size:0x3]
    [0x7f24844af3c0] malloc+0x0
    [0x7f218c0000b0]
    [0x7f218c004000000]

+++ Leaked Allocation [allocation size: 0x3 count:0x1 total size:0x3]
    [0x7f24844af3c0] malloc+0x0
    [0x7f21940000a0]
    [0x21940f4f0000007f]

+++ Leaked Allocation [allocation size: 0x3 count:0x1 total size:0x3]
    [0x7f24844af3c0] malloc+0x0
    [0x7f218da09f80]
    [0x7f218c004000000]


Total leaked: 0x63a6d9
```

There are no memory addresses that I can use to inspect the content or attempt to determine where the leak originates from.
As you can see, the address below each "Leaked Allocation" is for the malloc-call, all with the same address.

I do know that the memory leak is within the unmanaged code, so using the normal dotnet or sos methods to find the leak does not help.

Could someone help me understand how this information can help me figure out where and how the memory leaks are occurring?